# How to trigger browser's find (ctrl+F) on button click.

Tags: html

That is when i click on a button 
 it should fire browser's find event 
 and browser's find pop up should appear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Browser Search (Ctrl+F) through a button in website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080217/use-browser-search-ctrlf-through-a-button-in-website)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I programmatically trigger the search of my browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41297650/how-can-i-programmatically-trigger-the-search-of-my-browser)

Answer (score 0):

You can set your button to call Javascripts window.find function. Works in Chrome and Firefox and possibly Edge.

**Javascript**

```
findString = function findText(text) {
  window.find(text);
  alert("String \x22" + text + "\x22 found? " + window.find(text));
}
```

**HTML**

```
<p>Apples, Bananas, and Oranges.</p>
<button type="button" onClick='findString("Apples")'>Search for Apples</button>
<button type="button" onClick='findString("Banana")'>Search for Banana</button>
<button type="button" onClick='findString("Borange")'>Search for Borange</button>
```

Here is a website for reference.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/find

Comment: I dont want the find to happen as given above. Just need the pop up to appear,

How does the browser's find pop up appears when a user clicks Ctrl+F keys on a keyboard. Need to mimic that